# Import in Solidity.. Does it affect the Gas?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix

If I have 3 contracts.. Contract C imports contract B which imports Contract A...
Contract A is first deployed, then B, then C..

Contact B is created from within Contract A

and Contract C is created from within Contract B

Does this mean that Contract C needs the largest Gas as it imports from B and A? Contract B and C are the same type but A is different ..

I need an explanation to know if importing a code to another contract affects the gas consumption or not ...

For instance is it better to have one contract that other contracts only import from so like one parent and many children

or to have a contract that imports from another contract which imports from another one and so on.. like a chain .. will the last contract in the chain have all the code from the others ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The imports themselves do nothing to the compiled contract size and may even include code that is not included in the output bytecode. They merely make the code visible to the compiler so it can refer to the code, if needed.

If a factory contract A is to deploy an instance contract B, then the bytecode of the instance contract B is a hard coded into the factory contract A. That is, A "knows" how to deploy a B.

```
contract B {}

contract A {}
  B b;
  function createNewB() public {
    b = new B();
  }
}
```

You can organise your source code for re-use and this makes no difference to the compiler.

```
import "./B.sol";

contract A {}
  B b;
  function createNewB() public {
    b = new B();
  }
}
```

You can have another client contract C that needs to send/receive messages to B. There are two ways to do that. One is expensive, the other is inexpensive.

```
contract B {
   function foo() public {
     // do stuff
   }
}

contract C {
  B b;
  function doBFoo() {
    b.foo();
  }
}
```

In this case, all of B was compiled into C. This was necessary because we cast a variable `b` as type `B` which is a contract. Therefore, we got the works.

The alternative is to include only the surface area of B - the function signatures that C will talk to, but not the instructions inside the functions. Interface contracts are sets of undefined functions.

```
contract BInterface {
  function foo() public; 
}

contract B is BInterface {
   function foo() public {
     // do stuff
   }
}

contract C {
  BInterface b;
  function doBFoo() public {
    b.foo();
  }
}
```

In this case, C will include the much more compact BInterface which describes the function signatures but not the instructions inside each function.

In case it isn't clear, in each case (except `b = new B()`) you need a contract address. This is often done in a constructor.

For example, if we say:

`B b;`

We are saying there is a `B` called `b`. `B` is defined with `contract B` so `B` is a contract with a known interface, but where is it? `b` isn't much good unless it also has an address. Something like

```
function C(address bAddress) public {
   b = B(bAddress);
}
```

It will also work as

```
function C(address bAddress) public {
  b = BInterface(bAddress);
}
```

If this contract only wants to communicate with instances of `B` then the interface is the only needed information.

Interfaces are a solution to chains of imported code and they solve for circular dependencies. For example, if A needs to talk to B and B needs to talk to A.

```
contract AInterface{}
contract BInterface{}
contract A is AInterface {
  BInterface b;
}
contract B is BInterface {
  AInterface a;
}
contract FactoryInterface {}
contract Factory is FactoryInterface {
  A a;
  B b;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the  detailed explanation. Just wanted to ask about the case where contract C references contract BInterface and called b.foo(); ... how would contract C know the implementation of the function since it just includes the interface ...

Comment: It doesn't need to know about the implementation of the function - only how to form a message and hear a response. This is how C is comparatively smaller than it would have to be if it included all the compiled B functions. It doesn't need the B functions. That's B's job.