# Import existing code in Solidity, does it affect contract gas price?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, contract-design, gas-price

I understand that import your own code in smart contract effect it's gas price (you can find more here: [Import in Solidity.. Does it affect the Gas?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/45290/import-in-solidity-does-it-affect-the-gas))

But what about already existing code?

Let's say I'm doing `import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";` that also has tone of dependencies. But there are already tone of deployed contracts that uses same code. Will I pay for deploying all this dependencies, too? Or it will has different price and use some reuse engine?

Thank you

Comment: U will pay gas. I think in solidity you can only use deployed external libraries if u want but it will probably just save some deployment gas but make each call then more expensive and it is also not a good idea. People lost millions cause of that.

Comment: @MajdTL thank you for the answer

Comment: https://medium.com/coinmonks/all-you-should-know-about-libraries-in-solidity-dd8bc953eae7